# What is the difference between `root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` and `root ALL=(ALL) ALL`?

Tags: sudo

This line is from my Ubuntu 14.04

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

What is the meaning of the third `ALL`?

What is the difference between the above line and `root ALL=(ALL) ALL`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While the [`sudoers` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sudoers) can be a bit initmidating, there are examples given which help clarify things:

> ```
>  dgb     boulder = (operator) /bin/ls, (root) /bin/kill, /usr/bin/lprm
> ```
>
> Then user `dgb` is now allowed to run `/bin/ls` as `operator`, but `/bin/kill`
>   and `/usr/bin/lprm` as `root`.
>
> We can extend this to allow `dgb` to run `/bin/ls` with either the user or
>   group set to `operator`:
>
> ```
>  dgb     boulder = (operator : operator) /bin/ls, (root) /bin/kill,\
>          /usr/bin/lprm
> ```

We can infer that, given a `sudoers` line of the form:

```
A B = (C:D) E
```

`D` refers to the groups that can be used.

So the third `ALL` specifies that the user has can run the command under any group.

---

If the `(ALL)` is specified instead of `(ALL:ALL)`, then `sudo` cannot be used with `-g` by that user for those commands:

```
Runas_Spec
  A Runas_Spec determines the user and/or the group that a command may 
  be run as.             ...  The second defines a list of groups that
  can be specified via `sudo`'s `-g` option.  If both Runas_Lists are
  specified, the command may be run with any combination of users and
  groups listed in their respective Runas_Lists. If only the first is
  specified, the command may be run as any user in the list but no `-g`
  option may be specified.
```

(The examples above come from the same section.)

Comment: in above example can any one help me to understand what is `boulder`

Comment: @Arun `boulder` is a hostname. In most common situations today, you would just be using `ALL` to match all hosts.

Answer (score 5):

Found an interesting [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file)

**root   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL**

- The first field indicates the username that the rule will apply to
  (root).
- First “ALL” indicates that this rule applies to all hosts.
- Second “ALL” indicates that the root user can run commands as all
  users.
- Third “ALL” indicates that the root user can run commands as all
  groups.
- Forth “ALL” indicates these rules apply to all commands.